# Can't seem to conditionally compile for iPhone/Mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, macros

I've got this source (xcode 3.2.5):

```
NSLog(@"IPHONE = %d, SIMULATOR = %d, MAC = %d", TARGET_OS_IPHONE, TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR, TARGET_OS_MAC);
```

And I get this result:

```
2012-03-30 13:50:06.777 MyApp[36810:207] IPHONE = 1, SIMULATOR = 1, MAC = 1
```

No wonder my `#if` statements are confused!

What gives?  Any ideas?

**FWIW**:  On (tethered) iPod Touch I get this: `IPHONE = 1, SIMULATOR = 0, MAC = 1`

**Added**:  Well, I figured out that my original problem with `#if` was due to misspelling `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` as `TARGET_OS_PHONE` in several places.  (Good ol' copy/paste!)

Would still like to find a definitive description of how Apple's defines are supposed to be set.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, what is your target set for?

Comment: "Targeted device family: iPhone"

Answer (score 3):

Use `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` (only!) for differentiating between iOS and OSX.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
// iOS
#else
// Mac OS X
#endif
```

`TARGET_OS_MAC` will be 1 on both OSX and iOS; it predates iOS, and iOS is considered a variant of OSX as far as TargetConditionals.h is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but my assumption was that `TARGET_OS_MAC` specifies that you are building for Mac OS X (as opposed to, say, win32). iOS is actually a version of Mac OS X (although it is not branded / marketed as such).

To see how they are all defined, choose a build target and command-click their definition in xcode.

In the header file, the macros are defined as such:

```
TARGET_OS_MAC           - Generate code will run under Mac OS
TARGET_OS_WIN32         - Generate code will run under 32-bit Windows
TARGET_OS_UNIX          - Generate code will run under some non Mac OS X unix 
TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED      - Generate code will run under an embedded OS variant
                          of TARGET_OS_MAC
TARGET_OS_IPHONE        - Generate code will run under iPhone OS which 
                          is a variant of TARGET_OS_MAC.
```

So, it can be expected that `TARGET_OS_MAC` is defined for iOS, as well as `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` for example.

Comment: Command-click should find the definition for the scheme and target configuration that you have selected in Xcode.

Comment: "Should" and "does" are two different things.  Especially with Xcode.

Comment: See the updated answer. By the way, since Xcode switched to LLVM/clang, my impression is that code navigation and refactoring works exceptionally well (at least compared to other C/C++/objC IDEs I've seen).